# Tesseract OCR implementation in Windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: windows-phone, ocr, tesseract

Q. Not able to add Tesseract-OCR to References in windows phone application.

I have added "Install-Package Tesseract" from nuget manager. I am not able to refer it my application.

Can anyone please guide me through.

Thanks in advance.